# How to restrict ffmpeg to use only 50% of my CPU?

Tags: ffmpeg

i m using ffmpeg for streaming my desktop over UDP but my problem is ffmpeg's process always takes 100% cpu for the entire time it is running leaving no room other application , my question is how can i restrict ffmpeg's process to take up only 50-60% of cpu ?

My cpu has single core 
2 gb ram

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: How much CPU is actually dedicated to the process depends on the OS task scheduler, based on priority level. Other more important tasks should go first though.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the quick reply , i m using windows 7 os 32 bit ,the priority of ffmpeg is normal, i have even tried using low priority but still it takes up all the cpu power

Comment: see http://superuser.com/a/214572/57579

Comment: @zukes it will still take 100% until something with more priority comes along to compete.   You canot set it to only be 50% when nothing else is going on.  It doesn't work like that.  It will go to 100% till you fire up something with more priority.   At which point ffmpeg may go down well below 50%

Answer (score 33, accepted):

FFMpeg has an option  `-threads`. You can define there, if it's going to be `auto` (default) or you can limit the number of used threads (CPU cores). Recommended that you set your number based on the amount of available threads minus 1, or 2. So if you have 8 threads, setting to `-threads 6` would be great. But if you have only one core and 2 gb of RAM, I'm not sure if this is the case! FFMpeg requires a lot of resources.

Comment: See [How to change ffmpeg -threads settings](https://superuser.com/a/792609/267546), you have to put `-threads x` just before the output argument.

Comment: Odd. It was first using 100% of all 4 cores. I used `-threads 2` and now it's using 50% of all 4 cores instead of 100% of 2 cores.