# Limit the cpu usage when converting youtube videos to mp3 using youtube-dl

Tags: php, nginx, avconv, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl & avconv with php on nginx server to convert youtube video into mp3. Using htop I noticed the usage of cpus peak at 100% when couple of  avconv processes are running at the same time, and once my server crushed down because of that.

The first solution that I encountered [cpulimit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-on-ubuntu-12-10) but after some research,I've found cpu limit is not smart enough to handle multiple simultaneous instances.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107206/how-to-restrict-ffmpeg-to-use-only-50-of-my-cpu) I learned that I can limit the number of cpu threads using `-threads` option.
My basic command: `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <video URL>`

I wonder if I can add -threads option to the youtube-dl command, I am not sure if that is possible.

I have 2 cores cpu server, I am thinking of upgrading to 4 cores cpu and limit the avconv to use just 2 cores, what do you think ? Is that the best way to go (using thread option) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `--postprocessor-args '-threads N'`.

Comment: I've just tested it, and I passed  '-threads 1' option to ffmpeg process, but I can still see the both cores 100% fully consumed. I could see that using htop. I may have misunderstanding about how - threads works, I have 2 cpu cores, shouldn't just only one core to be consumed ?

Comment: I think it's working, when one ffmpeg process run at the time, I can see the cpu consumes only 100% from one core. So I suppose the other core was being consumed when multiple ffmpeg  processes running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using youtube-dl embedded add

```
'postprocessor_args': ['-threads', 'some_integer']
```

to the ydl_opts dict